# I can't get my line graph to plot correctly using jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, linegraph

I want to plot a graph with the following as the xaxis:

```
var xaxis = [31.1,31.2,31.3,31.4,31.5, 32.1,32.2,32.3,32.4,32.5];
```

notice how there is a skip between 31.5 and 32.1. However, when I plot my line graph, there is a large space between these two points. Here's my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                var cust1 = [[31.1,10],[31.2,15],[31.3,25],[31.4, 60],[31.5,95]];
                var cust2 = [[31.1,0],[31.2,15],[31.3,30],[31.4, 50],[31.5,85]];

                var data = [];
                data.push(cust1);
                data.push(cust2);

                var xaxis = [31.1,31.2,31.3,31.4,31.5, 32.1,32.2,32.3,32.4,32.5];

                var plot3 = $.jqplot('line-chart', data, 
                  { 
                      title:'Design Progress', 

                      axes: {
                          xaxis: {
                              //renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,
                              label: 'Work Weeks',

                              ticks: xaxis
                          },
                          yaxis: {
                              label: "Percent Complete",
                              max: 100,
                              min: 0
                          }
                      }
                  }
                );

            });
```

I think it's because I'm not specifying a renderer option in my xaxis options. However, I've tried to use $.jqplot.LineRenderer and $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer without any luck (I even set my xaxis values as strings but that didn't work). Anybody know what's going on?

Here's a pic to further clarify:

[image]

Comment: So you've left out the ticks between 31.5 and 32.1 because you don't want any text there to make room for the axis title "Work Weeks". But now there aren't any vertical lines either and you do want those. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: @flup no, The Work Weeks title is completely separate. I don't want a gap in my graph at all. My data that I'm using just skips from 31.5 to 32.1

Comment: to be even clearer, my workweeks represent a week in the year, and each week has a 1 through 5 (monday through friday). thanks

Comment: Aha, well, yes. Then this happened cause the jqplot was interpreting the numbers you give it as values, not as labels. And there is a gap of size 0.6 between 31.5 (thirty-one and a half) and 32.1 (thirty-two and one tenth).

Comment: Take a look at the http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-categoryAxisRenderer-js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it happens : jQuery flot library is building the graph with values that determined by your data.

When you provide such data, the plugin will set the axis values to be as same as the text and with the borders of the numbers you gave.
what you can do, is set the text to be different than the axis value.

You can easily do it by `options.xaxis.ticks.push([value, "the text"])`.

Pay attention that you are the one who is going to set which label will have which axis value, and this calls for setting the options parameter before calling the `$plot`

Comment: if I use your above method, would I have to push each tick individually? or could I pass in the list of numbers I've already created (just as strings)?

Comment: you can concat the array of ticks with another array, but it must be in a way that every cell in the ticks array contains an array of 2 cells, the first one is the axis value (int preferable) and the second one is the text (int/string preferable).

Comment: @roshambo would like to get a feedback here :)

Comment: I am still a little confused on where to place the line you gave. When I place it before where I define plot3 I get an error saying options is not defined

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I could define my ticks like so: ticks: [[1,"31.1"],[2,"31.2"]] etc

Comment: yes! that did the trick. I also had to adjust my data points too. For example, my cust1 list had to have numbers 1 through 10 instead of my numbers - 31.1, 31.2 etc. thanks!

Comment: @roshambo happy it worked for you, sorry i wasn't online to help you when you previously asked questions in the comment :)